# How to reset UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am developing a card game using UICollectionView. I override the **draw()** function of the UICollectionViewCell to arrange my images when load the cells. Every new game, i change the number of cards in the game. So the number and size of the cells change. I have to do all operations for UICollectionView in the **viewWillAppear()** method because of the third part library i use. My question is that how to reset all the works which done over the UICollectionView before. I want clear UICollectionView during each game without loading UIViewController again. Wanna do it in **viewWillAppear()** method. I want to clear UICollectionView because my images overlap if don't have clear UICollectionView in new game.

**Note** : I removed all the subviews from UICollectionView like below, but it didn't work

```
   let subViews = gameCollectionView.subviews

    if subViews != nil {
        for view in subViews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a class for the UICollectionView in which the data is loaded and delete the UICollectionView and it to the UIView again to reload it. I dno the reloadData is always the method I used but you say you can't use that

Comment: I don't understand how your collection view works or is supposed to work. What do you want to clear exactly? What is the third party library? What are the operations you do in viewWillAppear? I don't think right now there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: Do not override the `draw` method of `UICollectionView`. And why would you remove the subviews of a collection view? Nothing you are doing sounds correct.

Comment: To which view do you add your images?

Comment: I add my images to the contentView of the UICollectionViewCell in the draw method of it @RobertDresler

Comment: `draw` is called many times , you should create outlet for the properties or add them once , you can use `awakeFromNib` or once inside `layoutSubviews` if you need the correct bounds

Answer (score 3):

Clearing the collection is from clearing it's dataSource array like

```
arr = []
gameCollectionView.reloadData()
```

if you need to clear the cell then do it inside `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = ///
cell.contentView.subviews//// clear here
```

or override

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
 super.prepareForReuse()
 // clear any subview here
}
```

if you correctly assign values for all properties of the collection cell every run of `cellForRowAt` without adding subviews , then you'll have no overlappings

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove every subview from each cell's `contentView`, not from your collection view

```
gameCollectionView.visibleCells.forEach { $0.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } }
```

But, I'm not sure for what you need to override `draw` method. You should rather create what you need just once, for example in `awakeFromNib` and then you should just change properties of your image views, etc. depending on content, for this you purpose you can use collection view's data source method `cellForItemAt`.

Comment: Where are you adding these images? To which view

Comment: You should not remove all subviews of a collection view cell.

Comment: @nihasmata ok, check edited answer with `contentView`

Comment: @RobertDresler Thank you, it removes subviews but now the problem is that CollectionViewCell draw() method is not called for the old cells.It reuses the old ones. Think that i specified 20 cards (CollectionViewCel) for the first game, so draw() method called 20 times and add my images to content view of the CollectionViewCell. Then next game i specify 30 cards, but this time  draw() method called 10 times (30-20). I want to reset all the things about CollectionView. I want to call draw() method 30 times for the second game.